# ColdFusion Form Processing and Updating

Tags: mysql, forms, coldfusion

I'm hoping someone will have the answer! I have a .CFM page where a user can select a name from a drop down list (populated by querying a name column in MySQL database.

However, I am trying to get the user to select a name from the drop down list, click 'GO' and then be taken to a form where fields are pre-populated with data already associated with that 'name' e.g. address, DOB etc. Here a user can update the record.

I have managed to create the form and create the validation needed there (e.g. checking for numerical values etc). I just can't get the pre-populated data in there!!!

Thanks.

Comment: OK, so clicking 'go' results in a GET request to the next page, right? This will presumably have a ?name_id=X query string. So, you need to look up the person data using that primary key. Can you elaborate what part you're stuck on?

Comment: Thanks, yes its getting the information associated with that name populated on the page after 'GO'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the form will post the user id.

```
<form action="/landingpage.cfm" method="post">
    <select name="user">
        <option value="1">Name</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

So on landingpage.cfm you will need to get the data for that name from the database and use that to set the value of the form inputs.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "user")>

<cfquery name="getNameInformation" datasource="some-db">
    SELECT address FROM ... WHERE id = <cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_integer" value="form.user" />
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="getNameInformation">
     <input type="text" name="address" value="#address#">
</cfoutput>

</cfif>
```

Comment: Thank you, How would I enter this so it links the 'selection' page with the drop down list and the page where it can be updated?

Comment: adress -> address. I would fix it myself, but S/O won't accept it!

Comment: @ez87 I have updated the question. Hopefully that makes it clear what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you! I think im following! However I seem to be getting an error as I try to process the page?                               24: <CFQUERY NAME="qNameUpdate" DATASOURCE="NamesDatabase">
25 : SELECT * FROM Names
26 : WHERE FirstName = #form.FirstName#
27 : </CFQUERY>

Comment: What's the error? Does if you dump out form.FirstName is it what you expect? `<cfdump var="#form.FirstName#" abort="true" />`

Comment: I think your problem is firstName is a varchar so you need `WHERE FirstName = '#form.FirstName#'` however I can't stress enough you need the cfqueryparam here from my answer otherwise you are asking to be hacked via sql injection. `<cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_varchar" value="form.FirstName" />`

Comment: So the problem is you are not posting firstName. Your form should have a select list with name="firstName" and an option with the name as the value so: `<select name="FirstName"><option value="james">James</option></select>`

Comment: The names in the list are automatically pre populated with names from the database so there isn't a value="James" etc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5943/discussion-between-bigfellahull-and-ez87)